# C++: Return the iterator pointing to element equally to the target

Tags: c++

I want to find out the iterator pointing to an element equal to the target.

The following code does not work for me, what's wrong with this code?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
typename std::vector<T>::iterator find_it(std::vector<T> vec, const int target){
    std::vector<T>::iterator it = vec.begin();
    while(it != vec.end() ){
        if(*it == target) return it;
        it++;
    }
    return vec.end();
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec {1,2,3,4,10};
    std::vector<int>::iterator res = find_it(vec, 1);
    std::cout << *(*res) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's good that you included a complete example, but it would help to be much more specific about "does not work for me". What exactly is wrong? (Although the problem is fairly "obvious" to someone experienced with C++, and there is already a correct answer).

Comment: I assume you just might want to implement that yourself for learning purposes. But for completeness, there is already [std::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) for that usecase. `auto res = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1);`

Comment: And `*(*res)` does not make much sense. `*res` results in an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vec` is passed by-value, it'll be destroyed when `find_it` returns, the returned iterator to it is dangling, dereference on the iterator leads to UB.

You can change it to pass-by-reference.

```
template <typename T>
typename std::vector<T>::iterator find_it(std::vector<T>& vec, const int target){
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator it = vec.begin();
    while(it != vec.end() ){
        if(*it == target) return it;
        it++;
    }
    return vec.end();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `find_it` function copies the original vector and returns an iterator to the copy.